# dnx and dnu not running on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: asp.net-core, dnx, .net-core, dnu

I have followed the instructions on docs.asp.net for Linux installation using `dnvm list` I can see that .NET Core is installed but when I enter just `dnx` or `dnu` it immediately returns and no message or error whatsoever.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: ASP.NET 5 is supported on 14.04, not 15.10.  See https://www.jeffogata.com/asp-net-5-on-linux/ for more info.  Full disclosure:  this is a post on my personal blog, if the url did not give it away :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now, dnx only runs on Ubuntu 14.04. Sorry...

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at this workaround: [dnx & dnu in 15.10](https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/issues/3059)

```
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/icu/libicu52_52.1-8ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb
dpkg -i libicu52_52.1-8ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb
```